# Replacing variables in a polynomial with their powers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Suppose I have a homogeneous polynomial $P(x,y,z)$ in three variables. Are there "general" statements about the polynomial $P'=P(x^k,y^k,z^k)$? I'm particularly interested in smoothness and irreducibility in the case where $P$ defines a smooth projective curve.

Comment: it's very broad. Could you add some conditions please ?

Comment: I'm just interested in building up some intuition of what might happen if I replace variables by their powers. In general I would expect smoothness and irreducibility to be preserved, though there are special cases where this is not the case. If anyone has results that only hold under certain conditions they still would be appreciated.

Comment: the main weird effects with smoothness may be the k parity and the way a power grows when its argument is > or < 1. Perhaps some expert will find a relevant theorem ...